# coreValidity is false. Verify XML digital signature

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature

I am doing some digital signing on XML files and I want to validate the XML that I have signed. I am using code samples from the Java XML Digital Signature API but when I go to verify the signature on the XML i've just signed

The **coreValidity** is false and the **sigValValidity** is true

What's the difference between these and why would the coreValidity be false? What can I look out for?

Thanks

```
public void verifySignedXML(KeyPair keypair) throws Exception {
        String signedFile = "src/test/resources/file.xml";


        // Instantiate the document to be validated
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
                new FileInputStream(signedFile));

        // Find Signature element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS,
                "Signature");
        if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot find Signature element");
        }

        // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to unmarshal the
        // document containing the XMLSignature
        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        if (keypair.getPublic() == null) {
            log.error("Public key is null");
            //TODO throw exception
        }

        PublicKey key = keypair.getPublic();

        // Create a DOMValidateContext and specify a KeyValue KeySelector
        // and document context
        DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(
                key, nl.item(0));

        // unmarshal the XMLSignature
        XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);

        // Validate the XMLSignature (generated above)
        boolean coreValidity = signature.validate(valContext);

        // Check core validation status
        if (coreValidity == false) {
            System.err.println("Signature failed core validation");
            boolean sv = signature.getSignatureValue().validate(valContext);
            System.out.println("signature validation status: " + sv);
            // check the validation status of each Reference
            Iterator<?> i = signature.getSignedInfo().getReferences().iterator();
            for (int j = 0; i.hasNext(); j++) {
                boolean refValid = ((Reference) i.next()).validate(valContext);
                System.out.println("ref[" + j + "] validity status: "
                        + refValid);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Signature passed core validation");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code. It is not possible to know what you are naming as `coreValidity` and `sigValValidity`

Comment: Updated question with code

Comment: In the output you should see something like "ref[i] validity status: false" where i is the index of Reference for which the validation failed. Probably digest calculation issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "core validation" validates the full signature according the rules defined in [XMLDsig standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-CoreValidation)

> The REQUIRED steps of core validation include (1) reference validation, the verification of the digest contained in each Reference in SignedInfo, and (2) the cryptographic signature validation of the signature calculated over SignedInfo.

If the core validation fails, then at least one of the validations performed on `Reference` or `SignatureValue` has failed. The rest of validation methods give you the details

But, take it carefully. Validating  XML signatures may fail for many weird reasons, even with valid signatures. In fact, the standard itself warns of it

> Note, there may be valid signatures that some signature applications are unable to validate. Reasons for this include failure to implement optional parts of this specification, inability or unwillingness to execute specified algorithms, or inability or unwillingness to dereference specified URIs (some URI schemes may cause undesirable side effects), etc.